# Update firstDayOfweek Angular Bootstrap Datepicker dynamically

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Experts.
I have problem to update the firstdayofweek using angular bootstrap datepicker.
Here is the plunker

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 4
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/O8AJ63gY6xHm1c2is9nI?p=preview (Without Rebuild)

The input box next 'Starting Day' has scope variable and I would like to change the first day of the week in date picker control.
Usually it can be done dateOptions.startingDay variable before template rendering, but it can't be changed dynamically.
I created an issue to angular bootstrap team and they replied to me dateOptions.startingDay variable is not watched variable and it can't be like that.
So I took an other example, destroying and rebuilding the template following this link

[How to re-render a template in an Angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080351/how-to-re-render-a-template-in-an-angular-directive)

, and build this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/R8yIvnwXzSZPfIWwBbDs?p=preview (Plunker)

If I inspect the element in this plunker, the new datepicker content is generated but, the dropdown is not working.

Any solutions would be welcome.
Thanks