# Why circle doesn't update?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Why the circle doesn't change his radius?

- plunker: [http://plnkr.co/edit/OlgflYVVXkPQPsbzc1q1?p=preview][1]

  ```
  aaaaaaa
  ```

  ```
  aaaaaaa
  ```

Comment: Can you post the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) directives are not updating, even when the values of the `radius` attribute are changing. I guess you already took a look into the attributes as well and saw, that even when the radius was growing the entire `<shape>` wasn't updating its appearance.

Due to this question and answer [How to re-render a template in an Angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080351/how-to-re-render-a-template-in-an-angular-directive) I was able to rerender the shapes with the help of that directive.

So wrapping the directive around the `<shape></shape>`

```
  <div relink-event="radiusUpdated">
    <shape name="circle" ng-repeat="post in posts" stroke-color="#FF0000" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="1" fill-color="#FF0000" fill-opacity="0.35" center="{{post.location}}" radius="{{post.postRadius*1000}}">
      {{post.postRadius}}
    </shape>
  </div>
```

And broadcasting the radiusUpdated in your $interval function now updates the shape in your map. I doubt that it is a very high performant way to do this (imagine to rerender hundreds of posts every two seconds), but maybe it is working in your case.

Here is a working Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/j0nO6MUCpf0Px2QwkKD1?p=preview

Would be nice if you upvote the refered answer by SO user [rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373655/rob) as well ;).