# Roll back ngOptions select to unselected state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

`ngOpions` creates a blank option like option html below if the model value doesn't match any of the option values:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

After a selection is made, AngularJS removes this first empty option html from the select html.

I have a use case where I want to roll back the state of the html select to the unselected option which AngularJS removed.  I tried `ngModel` methods like `$setPristine()`, `$rollbackViewValue()`, and `$setUntouched()`.  But none of these mothods puts the state of the select back to the initial state with the empty option.

Is it possible to truely roll back an AngularJS select element to have the empty option after a selection is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for `ngOptions` ([line 473 in ngOptions.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L473) ) suggests that only single-select can get it, and that the `writeValue` function (called when the `ngModel` changes) has to be invoked with a `null` value (not `undefined`, as `===` is used.)

So you can try setting your model variable to `null`.

If that doesn't work, I expect you may be out of luck as far as proper solutions go, and might need to re-render the whole directive. You can create a pretty simple directive to do that, similar to what's suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133080/624590